# CSRF Cookie Not Set error, Django Rest Framework Request Factory

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am unit testing a post method of a VIEW and getting a 403 response with the below error.

```
`def single_plate_pri(self):
    u = User.objects.get(username = 'c269880')
    self.client.force_authenticate(u)
    data = copy.deepcopy(self.valid_pri_data)
    factory = RequestFactory()
    post_url = '/sequence-request/confirm/'
    request = factory.post(post_url, data, user= u, 
    simulation_mode = True, enforce_csrf_checks=True)
    request.user = User.objects.get(username='c269880')
    view = csrf_exempt(SequencingRequestSpreadsheetView().as_view())
    resp = view(request)
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)`
```

Error :

> {'detail': ErrorDetail(string='CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set.',
>   code='permission_denied')}

I even tried csrf on the view but it did not work.

Comment: I suggest you modify the title, as currently it gives some context (which is good), but does not give any clue as to your question.

Answer (score 0):

add csrf_exempt to your `view.py`:

`from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

than use that this type:

```
@csrf_exempt
 def single_plate_pri(self):
    u = User.objects.get(username = 'c269880')
    self.client.force_authenticate(u)
    data = copy.deepcopy(self.valid_pri_data)
    factory = RequestFactory()
    post_url = '/sequence-request/confirm/'
    request = factory.post(post_url, data, user= u, 
    simulation_mode = True, enforce_csrf_checks=True)
    request.user = User.objects.get(username='c269880')
    view = csrf_exempt(SequencingRequestSpreadsheetView().as_view())
    resp = view(request)
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Usually you want to keep CSRF for your views, since it's a security feature.